# Making UI Generic For Every Phone

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, view

Making an application for android i noticed that the layout view on eclipse is different from the application layout view on my phone when i run my application on the phone. Talking about the position of widgets including buttons, image view, custom views. The placement is different in the application layout view on eclipse from that on phone. I was thinking that this means it would variate on different models of the android phones on which the application would be run. How can i make my view generic in order to cater this issue so that the position of the widgets be same no matter where the application is being run? Is it possible to cater this issue?

Comment: do a little search about "supporting multiple screens", there are plenty of articles about it.

Comment: i see something like adding screen support to the android manifest. Wouldn't it limit my application to certain devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henry suggested in the comment, this Android dev article should be able to make all your dreams come true.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Literary everything you could ever need to know about formating for different size screens is in that.

Comment: i see something like adding screen support to the android manifest. Wouldn't it limit my application to certain devices?

Comment: Not at all. This should be covered by creating settings for multiple densities.

Answer (score 0):

I did [this](https://github.com/bitstars/SimpleUi) to generate UI elements which fit on any phone and have abstraction what elements I want to show and how they will look like:

[SimpleUi ( https://github.com/bitstars/SimpleUi )](https://github.com/bitstars/SimpleUi)

The generated UI (code below):

[image]

[The complete code to create this Android UI](https://github.com/bitstars/SimpleUi/blob/master/SimpleUiExamples/src/de/rwth/StartExampleUi.java):

[image]

I use it in real applications, not only for fast prototyping or dialogs and its well tested over the years. The concept is based on the model view control principle and for most common scenarios there are ready to use components which automatically look correct on any device. I don't say it should be used for any UI (e.g. listviews should be done by hand) but for most usecases this should be quite handy ;) Oh and feel free to fork it and improve it further if you want